# How to catch an index error

Tags: python

Given `mylist = [0, 1]`

```
def catch_index_error(value):
    try:
        return value
    except IndexError:
        return None

catch_index_error(mylist[5])
```

returns an `IndexError`

The argument is evaluated prior to the function being executed and therefore the function can't catch the exception. Is there a way of catching it?

Comment: Added an answer with the usage of decorator. I believe you would be interested in checking that out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `mylist[5]` causes the `IndexError`, because it is evaluated *before* the function is called.

The only way to fix this is by letting the function return the correct value *from `mylist`*:

```
mylist = [0,1]
def catch_index_error(index):
  try:
     return mylist[index]
  except IndexError:
    return None

catch_index_error(0) # returns '0'
catch_index_error(4) # returns None
```

Comment: Thank you. This works and is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
try:
    catch_index_error(mylist[5])
except IndexError:
    do something
```

The error occurs in the call

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
try:
    mylist[5]
except IndexError:
    #your code
```

Answer (score 2):

All the answers mentioned here will suffice your requirement. But I believe the ideal way to achieve this is via using `decorator`. In fact they exist in python for such kind of scenarios. For example, create a decorator as:

```
def wrap_index_error(func):
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func_response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except IndexError:
            func_response = None
        return func_response
    return wrapped_func
```

Now you can use this decorator as `@wrap_index_error` in any function where you want to catch the `IndexError` exception. For example in your case:

```
@wrap_index_error
def get_item_from_list(my_list, index):
    return my_list[index]
```

Now you can make the simple call to access the value as:

```
>>> new_list = [1, 3, 5]
>>> print get_item_from_list(new_list, 2)
5
>>> print get_item_from_list(new_list, 8)
None
```

*Note:* I am passing list as the argument to function because it is not a good practice to update the global value within function. Instead passed it as a argument. That way your code will be more modular. For example, may be you want to perform the same operation on another list?

To know more about Decorators, check: [A guide to Python's function decorators](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/)