# Looping through Python array results in list index out of range error

Tags: python, loops

I have a multidimensional array with this format:

```
['201800053193', 'Jane Doe', 'PAUL', None, '1', None, '0', '2', 'N', 83]
```

There are about 4500 arrays like this inside of another array.

Im looping through it with this:

```
for ent in entity_array:
    print(ent[9])
```

But Im getting an error at the end:

```
in entities
    print(ent[9])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Element ent[9] does exist for each sub-array. What could be causing this error?

Looping through this does not give an error:

```
for ent in entity_array:
    print(ent)
```

Comment: Add `print(ent)` just before `print(ent[9])` and you'll find the culprit.

Comment: One (at least) of the (big array) items, has less than 10 elements. Try  `print(len(ent))` before `ent[9]`, and also you could use `enumerate` to get the faulty list index in the big 2D array.

Comment: Use try catch to see which part of the array is causing this issue. More details about catching IndexError is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604377/how-to-catch-an-index-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it suggests that at least one of the subarray has the length less than or equal 9.

you can try the following code to check the lengths first

```
for ent in entity_array:
    print(len(ent))
```

Comment: I just realized it, the header array is missing an element. thank you