# Python IndexError list out of Range

Tags: python, indexing, beautifulsoup, range

I'm pretty new to python and I'm having trouble continuing or passing this error. I know that Index wont work but I just want to pass by it.
I'm getting the Error on Week 3 because nothing is there.

> league_table11 = league_table30.find_all(class_="viCellBg2
> cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[8] IndexError: list index out of
> range

https://www.vegasinsider.com/nfl/matchups/matchups.cfm/week/3/season/2021

```
import pandas as pd

import requests

import bs4

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


n=range(2,18)
h=range(2,18)   ##### Change to 17
a=range(2,7)   ##### Change to 2,14


url2 ='https://www.vegasinsider.com/nfl/matchups/matchups.cfm/week/'

url3 ='/season/2021'

### for n in n:  

for a in range(1,18):
 
    all = url2+str(a)+url3 ##### change 1 to n
    if a == (None):
        continue

    r = requests.get(all)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    if soup == (None):

                    continue
    for n in range(2,18):
        league_table2 = soup.find_all(class_ = 'SLTables1')[n]
        if league_table2 == (None):

                    continue
        if league_table2 == IndexError:
                    continue
        GAME = league_table2.find(class_ = "viHeaderNorm")
        if GAME == (None):

                    continue
        Teamname = league_table2.find_all(class_= "viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padLeft")[0]
        if Teamname == (None):

                    continue
        league_table3 = league_table2.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[0]
        if league_table3 == (None):

                    continue
        league_table4 = league_table2.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[1]
        if league_table4 == (None):

                    continue
        league_table5 = league_table2.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[2]
        if league_table5 == (None):

                    continue
        league_table6 = league_table2.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[3]
        if league_table6 == (None):

                    continue
        league_table7 = league_table2.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[4]
        if league_table7 == (None):

                    continue
        print(a, GAME.text, Teamname.text, league_table3.text, league_table4.text, league_table5.text, league_table6.text, league_table7.text)
    for h in range(2,18):
        league_table30 = soup.find_all(class_ = 'SLTables1')[h]
        if league_table30 == (None):

                    continue
        if league_table30 == IndexError:
                    continue
        GAME1 = league_table30.find(class_ = "viHeaderNorm")
        if GAME1 == (None):

                    continue
        Teamname1 = league_table30.find_all(class_= "viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padLeft")[3]
        if Teamname1 == (None):

                    continue
        league_table8 = league_table30.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[5]
        if league_table8 == (None):

                    continue
        league_table9 = league_table30.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[6]
        if league_table9 == (None):

                    continue
        league_table10 = league_table30.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[7]
        if league_table10 == (None):

                    continue
        if league_table10 == 0:
                    continue
        if league_table10 == IndexError:
                    pass       
        league_table11 = league_table30.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[8]
        if league_table11 == (None):
                    continue
        if league_table11 == 0:
                    continue
        if league_table11 == IndexError:
                    pass
        league_table12 = league_table30.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")[9]
        if league_table12 == (None):

                    continue
        if league_table12 == 0:
                    continue
        if league_table12 == IndexError:
                    continue
        print(a, GAME1.text, Teamname1.text, league_table8.text, league_table9.text, league_table10.text, league_table11.text, league_table12.text)
        #print(league_table30)
```

Comment: to handle index errors look at try except blocks .e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604377/how-to-catch-an-index-error

Answer (score 0):

IndexError means that you're referring to an invalid index. In this case you're trying to refer to the 9th element of a list, but the list has less than
9 elements!

To confirm this, if you run the line below you'll see that the length of this list is actually 8.

```
print(len(league_table30.find_all(class_="viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter")))
```

You've either put in the wrong index, are using the wrong list, or you need to do some investigating.

Comment: They know this. They want to know how to get their program to continue.